# Can I not submit a form to a servlet from JSF?

Tags: forms, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

```
*  Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/home.xhtml' for action 'MemoServlet' with outcome 'MemoServlet'
```

I try to accomplish it through:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="add" action="MemoServlet"/>
```

but all the tutorials in the world only do it with a bean, which i don't want. I've come across any navigation rule that accomplishes my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why a servlet? What exactly is the functional requirement? Doesn't the servlet contain "too much" code which you could just refactor into a separate class and import/call that in both the original servlet and the JSF bean action method?

Anyway, to fix the particular problem, you need either a plain vanilla HTML `<form>` element whose `action` points to the servlet URL or to call [`ExternalContext#dispatch()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#dispatch%28java.lang.String%29) on the servlet URL inside the bean's action method.

Comment: why a bean?! I thought mvc wanted pages to interface to servlets which in turn call the factored code you want.

Comment: JSF is a MVC framework with the FacesServlet as the sole controller so that you basically end up with a bean as model and a JSP/Facelets page as view. Why adding another servlets? Sounds like as a servlet with tight coupled code. You should have a business/domain object which does the business task which in turn can be called from JSF bean or a "plain vanilla" servlet.

Comment: but calling 'userManager.validate' is not it already business logic?

Comment: What is it then doing in a servlet? A servlet is there to control, preprocess and postprocess HTTP requests, not to do business logic. Just call `userManager.validate` in your bean action.